# How does Mechanica "resist" a punch?

Tags: arms

Mechanica's ability 2 is written as

> Ability 2: Will not flinch from non-charged (and some charged) attacks while jumping, dashing, or punching; also gain 50% damage reduction when a punch is resisted

What does it mean, a punch is resisted? Is that the same as receiving a punch but not flinching? Or that a charged punch still didn't make her flinch? I don't understand the meaning.

Comment: it would be nice if people downvote, they could explain why so i could fix the question

Comment: [Because Tim lost his keys](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/193762)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that when Mechanica gets hit by a punch meeting the criteria for her non-flinching ability, that punch will only do 50% damage. Obviously, also, she will not flinch from that punch.